# Report/Power BI server e-mail subscription: change original web-link into alias

Tags: reporting-services, powerbi, powerbi-desktop, power-bi-report-server, reportserver

Would you help me, please, to change original web-link into alias in my Power BI Server.

Details:
My Power BI is installed on a server with complicated name.
To simplify the name, I've added an alias to sever name.
Now I can enter power bi portal by 2 links:

http://complicated-server-name/Reports/browse/

http://simple-server-name(alias)/Reports/browse/

The problem is, every time I create email subscription and include a link into e-mail, a link into complicated-server-name is automatically generated.

I can substitute it on the alias-link by hand, but it does not accord to security context of my company.

Answer (score 0):

Find here:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Power BI Report Server\PBIRS\ReportServer\rsreportserver.config
```

a tag UrlRoot and input in it a link to your alias server.

```
Example: <UrlRoot>http://alias/ReportServer/</UrlRoot>
```